# How do I pass the controller by other means than the url in PHP MVC

Tags: php, url-routing, clean-urls

I realize this may be a dumb question, but I am struggling with a custom MVC project I started in order to learn PHP and I was not able to find what I was looking for anywhere else.

My question is, how do I pass the controller to my router, in a way that does not use the url. How would I make it so that the href in my link tags only provide the category and id and yet make it work. At the moment my urls look like this:

**website/controller/method/args**

**ex: website/articles/post/13**

I want the url to be like:

**website/category/id-or-slug-from-title**

I would really appreciate the help, since it's been bugging me for a week now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you can create table with routes and store there `route, controller, method and args`. And then, in your router make an attempt to find path in this table. If not found, try to resolve it dynamically.

Comment: I'd suggesting using an existing framework. I'm rather partial to Codeigniter. Laravel is okay too, if you can meet the requirements, but CI is more user-friendly, in my opinion. Especially for beginners. Writing your own routing class is great and all, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Rulisp That may be a good idea, but I still don't know how to get the param itself to compare it to. If the href only has the article category and id, how do I pass the controller parameter is what I don't know.

Comment: @Joe I'm trying to write my own so I better understand the relationship between the different parts of MVC and to practice OOP. Using an existing framework will not help me.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it would be hard to describe possible steps in comment section, so I will add an answer.

The following steps will be exemplary and they do not describe the whole process. I will omit some details

1. Assuming that you're trying to implement MVC, you should have some kind of bootstrap.php (or something like that)
2. So, let's create our router class

   ```
   /**
    * Current method
    * @var string
    */
   protected $method;

   /**
    * Current args
    * @var unknown
    */
   protected $args = array();  

   private static $instance;

   /**
    * That's how we retrieve class instance
    * @return app_router_http
    */
   public static function getInstance()
   {
       if (!isset(static::$instance))
       {
           static::$instance = new self;
       }

       return static::$instance;
   }

   private function __clone() {}

   /**
    * @throws app_exception
    */
   private function __construct()
   {
       /* парсим текущий урл */
       $url = parse_url (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "/", PHP_URL_PATH);

       $url = preg_replace("/\\/{2,}/i", "/", $url);

       /* Let's retrieve static route (for example - /category/id-or-slug-from-title) */
       if ($_route = $this->getStaticRoute($url))
       {
           if ($_route->hasErrors())
           {
               throw new app_exception($_route->getErrors(";"));
           }
           $this
               ->setController($_route->getController())
               ->setMethod($_route->getMethod())
               ->setArgs($_route->getArgs() ? $_route->getArgs() : null)
           ;

           return;
       }

       /* Let's retrive dynamic route, because we didn't fing static */
       if ($_route = $this->getDynamicRoute($url))
       {
           if ($_route->hasErrors())
           {
               throw new app_exception($_route->getErrors(";"));
           }

           $this
               ->setController($_route->getController())
               ->setMethod($_route->getMethod())
               ->setArgs($_route->getArgs() ? $_route->getArgs() : null);

           return;
       }

       throw new app_exception("Can't found any route objects", 503);
   }

   /**
    * @param string $controller
    * @return Router
    */
   public function setController($controller)
   {
       $this->controller = $controller;
       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * @return string
    */
   public function getController()
   {
       return $this->controller;
   }

   /**
    * @param string $method
    * @return Router
    */
   public function setMethod($method)
   {
       $this->method = $method;
       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * @return string
    */
   public function getMethod()
   {
       return $this->method;
   }

   /**
    * @param array $args
    * @return Router
    */
   public function setArgs(array $args = null)
   {
       if (isset($args))
       {
           $this->args = $args;
       }
       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function getArgs()
   {
       return $this->args;
   }           

   /**
    * @param string $route
    * @param string $controller
    * @param string $method
    * @param string $objectId
    * @return Route|NULL
    */
   public function getStaticRoute($route = null, $controller = null, $method = null, $objectId = null)
   {
       $db = new DB(); //Some class for db connections

       if (isset($route) && !isset($controller) && !isset($method) && !isset($objectId))
       {
           $selector = "SELECT * FROM `routes` WHERE `route` = '".$db->escape($route)."'";
       }

       if (!isset($route) && isset($controller) && isset($method) && isset($objectId))
       {
           $selector = "SELECT * FROM `routes` WHERE `controller` = '".$db->escape($controller)."' && `method` = '".$db->escape($method)."' && `objectId` = '".$db->escape($objectId)."'";
       }

       if (!isset($selector))
       {
           throw new app_exception(get_class($this)."::getStaticRoute incorrect params", 503);
       }

       if ($db->query($selector)->rows())
       {
           $row = $db->fetch();

           $object = new Router();
           $object->setAttributes($row);

           if (!$object->hasErrors())
           {
               $object->setController("{$object->getController()}");//Here we are setting our awesome controller

               if (!$this->isControllerExist($object->getController()))
               {
                   return $object->addError("Controller {$object->getController()} missing (static route: #{$object->getId()})");
               }

               if (!$this->isMethodExist($object->getController(), $object->getMethod()))
               {
                   return $object->addError("Method {$object->getMethod()} missing (controller: {$object->getController()}) (static route: #{$object->getId()})");
               }

           }

           return $object; 
       }

       return null;

   }

   /**
    * @param string $path
    * @return Router
    */
   public function getDynamicRoute($path)
   {
       $object = new Router;

       //Here we will assume that our url looks like this /controller/method/args

       /* Url fragments */
       $fragments = explode("/", substr($path, 1));

       //Removing trailing slash
       if (!$fragments[sizeof($fragments)-1])
       {
           unset($fragments[sizeof($fragments)-1]);
       }

       if (!isset($fragments[0]))
       {
           $fragments[0] = APP_ROUTE_DEFAULT_CONTROLLER; //Some kind of magic constant
       }

       $controller = $fragments[0];

       if(!class_exists($controller)
       {
           throw new Exception("Ooops, controller not found", 404);
       }

       array_shift($fragments); //We don't need controller element anymore


       for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++)
       {
           if ($i == 0)
           {
               $method = APP_ROUTE_DEFAULT_METHOD;//We also need to handle urls like /news. For example, each controllers has default method index()
           }
           else
           {
               $method = $fragments[0];
           }

           if ($this->isControllerExist($controller) && $this->isMethodExist($controller, $method))
           {
               return 
                   $object
                       ->setController($controller)
                       ->setMethod($method);
           }
       }       

       return $object->addError("Can't route to <strong>".implode("/", $fragments)."</strong> (dynamic route for module <strong>{$module}</strong>)");
   }

   /**
    * @param string $controller
    * @return boolean
    */
   public function isControllerExist($controller = null)
   {
       if (!isset($controller))
       {
           $controller = $this->getController();
       }

       return class_exists($controller);
   }

   /**
    * @param string $controller
    * @param string $method
    * @return boolean
    */
   public function isMethodExist($controller = null, $method = null)
   {
       if (!isset($controller))
       {
           $controller = $this->getController();
       }

       if (!isset($method))
       {
           $method = $this->getMethod();
       }
       return method_exists($controller, $method);
   }

   public function run()
   {
       $_str = $this->getController();
       $controller = new $_str;

       $return = call_user_func_array(array($controller, $this->getMethod()), $this->getArgs());

       return $return;
   }
   ```

   }
3. So, in bootstrap.php you just need to need to make a call `Router::getInstance()->run()`
4. Static route will try to pass your params
5. For dynamic routes, you always can read args from $_REQUEST

P.S. To be true, this is a cutted examaple made from my old project